# Floating point arithmetic ( IEEE-754 standard ) commutative law (*,+)

Tags: computational-mathematics, floating-point

How can I prove that: $ fl(a \ op \ b) = fl(b \ op \ a), \: op = +,*.$.

I have been reading and searching the big majority say that its true.
like [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5538365). However, I can not find a mathematical proof of it.

can someone give a hint of the demonstration?

Comment: As written, is trivial (see the answer). The more interesting question "are the floating point operations  $+$ and $\cdot$ commutative?" is implementation-dependent. True in the case of IEEE-754: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007400/is-multiplication-always-commutative-in-inexact-floating-point-arithmetic.

Comment: @BorbonJuggler Please clarify whether the question is restricted to floating-point arithmetic as defined by the IEEE-754 standard. If so, the answer by gammatester applies. If not: there have supposedly been machines in the past for which the equality did not hold. W.J. Cody's [paper](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/5515853) "Towards sensible floating-point arithmetic", COMPCON 1980, states that $X * Y \ne Y * X$ was possible on the Cray-1 (see table 1).

Comment: Yes, I meant in the IEEE-754 standard, already improve the question title.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial, because you have $a \ op \ b = b \ op \ a$ and therefore $fl(a \ op \ b) = fl(b \ op \ a).$

Comment: $fl(a \ op \ b) = (a \ op \ b) (1+\delta_1)$ and  $fl(b \ op \ a) = (a \ op \ b) (1+\delta_2)$ , so you have to show that the deltas are the same, that I imagine that IEEE 745 guarantee that.

Comment: No, the reasoning is much simpler: The $fl$ maps the mathematical result to the nearest floating point number. The mathematical results are the same and so are the results of the $fl$ rounding.

Comment: So what happens to an expression like that  $fl(a + a) = fl(2*a)$, supposing that $a$ cannot be represented exactly. following your reasoning, in this case, the rounding by nearest of the left side has a bigger error than the right one because $2$ can be represented without information lost.

Comment: Your last expression says nothing about commutativity of * or +, it even mixes operations.

Comment: I didn't mean that this expression says something about the commutativity of + or *, I wanted to say that is I have an expression like this $fl(a + a) = fl(2*a)$, the reason why is true follows the same reasoning you are saying for the previous one.

Comment: Yes, and it is true. Or do you have any floating point counter-example with $a+a \ne 2a?$

Comment: The only interesting case is where $a$ has the maximum binary exponent for the floating point format. For all smaller numbers, $fl(a+a)=fl(2∗a)=2fl(a)$ as the mantissa bits are the same in all 3 formulations.